# Increase horizontal spacing of (all) superscripts

Tags: xetex, superscripts, kerning

I am using a TrueType font with `XeLaTeX` and `unicode-math`, and I noticed that, because italic letters are very slanted, in math formulas superscripts are too close, sometimes they touch the letter. The problem is solved on a case by case basis by setting `$X^{\,\prime}$`. However, is there a way to change the spacing (kerning) for the whole document?

Comment: Trying to change the default space, it may leads to some other major issues...

Comment: Are you free to use Lua:LaTeX instead of XeLaTeX?

Comment: I have setup everything with XeLaTeX and it works well, except for this. Unless it is really necessary, or definitely better, I'd prefer not to move to LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Is there a solution with LuaLaTeX?